# Emulator display blank screen when trying to load data from local server

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, fragment, emulation

I'm trying to display some data from a local database, using RecyclerView in a fragment.
I have no errors, but still, when running the code, the emulator displays nothing.

However, the LogCat displays these messages as error :

*1831-1872/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property*

and

*2034-2248/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?)*

Please, any help ??

Thank you

**My class**

```
    private String SectorName;
    private String image_url;

    public sector_services() {};

    public sector_services (String SectorName, String image_url)
    {
        this.SectorName = SectorName;
        this.image_url = image_url;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return SectorName;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.SectorName = name;
    }

    public String getImage () { return image_url;}
    public void setImage(String image) {this.image_url = image;}
}
```

**My Adapter**

```
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        List<sector_services> sectors;
        Context c;

    //ViewHolder Class

    public class RecyclerVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView sectorName;
        ImageView image;

        public RecyclerVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            sectorName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.sector);
            image= itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_sector);
        }
    }


        public ServicesAdapter(Context ctx, List<sector_services> sectors) {
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
            this.sectors = sectors;
        }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_list_services,parent,false);
        return new RecyclerVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerVH holder, int position) {

        holder.sectorName.setText(sectors.get(position).getName());
        Picasso.with(c)
                .load(sectors.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sectors.size();
    }

}
```

**My Fragment**

```
    RecyclerView rv;
    List<sector_services> sectors;
    private static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/rankit_api/test.php";
    Adapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Inflate the layout for this fragment, the layout contains the list view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_services, container, false);
        
        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_service);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        sectors = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setAdapter(new ServicesAdapter(getActivity(),sectors));
        //rv.setAdapter((RecyclerView.Adapter) adapter);

        extractSectors();

        return view;
    }

    private void extractSectors() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, (JSONArray) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject sectorObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        sector_services sector = new sector_services();
                        sector.setName(sectorObject.getString("sector_name"));
                        sector.setImage(sectorObject.getString("sector_image"));
                        sectors.add(sector);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("tag", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

}
```